# Strange behaviour during multiprocess calls to numpy conjugate

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, cpu-cache

The attached script evaluates the numpy.conjugate routine for varying numbers of parallel processes on differently sized matrices and records the corresponding run times.
The matrix shape only varies in it's first dimension (from 1,64,64 to 256,64,64). Conjugation calls are always made on 1,64,64 sub matrices to ensure that the parts that are being worked on fit into the L2 cache on my system (256 KB per core, L3 cache in my case is 25MB). Running the script yields the following diagram (with slightly different ax labels and colors).

[image]

As you can see starting from a shape of around 100,64,64 the runtime is depending on the number of parallel processes which are used.

What could be the cause of this ?
Or why is the dependence on the number of processes for matrices below (100,64,64) so low?
My main goal is to find a modification to this script such that the runtime becomes as independent as possible from the number of processes for matrices 'a' of arbitrary size.

In case of 20 Processes:
all 'a' matrices take at most: 20 * 16 * 256 * 64 * 64 Byte = 320MB
all 'b' sub matrices take at most: 20 * 16 * 1 * 64 * 64 Byte = 1.25MB
So all sub matrices fit simultaneously in L3 cache as well as individually in the L2 cache per core of my CPU.
I did only use physical cores no hyper-threading for these tests.

Here is the script:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'

def f(q,size):
    a = np.random.rand(size,64,64) + 1.j*np.random.rand(size,64,64)
    start = time.time()
    n=a.shape[0]
    for i in range(20):
        for b in a:
            b.conj()
    duration = time.time()-start
    q.put(duration)

def speed_test(number_of_processes=1,size=1):
    number_of_processes = number_of_processes
    process_list=[]
    queue = Queue()
    #Start processes
    for p_id in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=f,args=(queue,size))
        process_list.append(p)
        p.start()
    #Wait until all processes are finished
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()

    output = []
    while queue.qsize() != 0:
        output.append(queue.get())
    return np.mean(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes=np.arange(1,20,3)
    data=[[] for i in processes]
    for p_id,p in enumerate(processes):
        for size_0 in range(1,257):
            data[p_id].append(speed_test(number_of_processes=p,size=size_0))

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    for d in data:
        ax.plot(d)
    ax.set_xlabel('Matrix Size: 1-256,64,64')
    ax.set_ylabel('Runtime in seconds')

    fig.savefig('result.png')
```

Comment: I know this is throwaway code, but you should get all your data from a queue before you join a process. `q.put` might get blocked waiting for `q.get` on the other side, while the other side is waiting on `p.join`, which is blocked by `q.put`. Also `q.qsize` and `q.empty` mostly only exists for interface compatibility with the non-multiprocessing `Queue` library. It is not reliable in certain circumstances (race condition with managing thread). `mp.manager` queues don't have this problem because they're a proxy to a non-mp queue (though that means they're slower too).

Comment: Thanks for the input. The standard way is then to send an additional "DONE" message from each Process in order to know when everything is finished ?

Comment: Either know how many workers you have, and expect that many "done" messages, or know how many outputs you have, and expect that many values. Your approach can also technically be made safe by providing timeouts to `get`, `put`, and `join`. It's good practice to "never wait forever"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to at least a combination of two complex effects: **cache-thrashing** and **frequency-scaling**. I can reproduce the effect on my 6 core i5-9600KF processor.

---

### Cache thrashing

The biggest effect comes from a cache-thrashing issue. It can be easily tracked by looking at the RAM throughput. Indeed, it is 4 GiB/s for 1 process and 20 GiB/s for 6 processes. The read throughput is similar to the write one so the throughput is symmetric. My RAM is able to reach up to ~40 GiB/s but usually ~32 GiB/s only for mixed read/write patterns. This means the RAM pressure is pretty big. Such use-case typically occurs in two cases:

- an array is read/written-back from/to the RAM because cache are not big enough;
- many access to different locations in memory are made but they are mapped in the same cache lines in the L3.

At first glance, the first case is much more likely to happen here since arrays are contiguous and pretty big (the other effect unfortunately also happens, see below). In fact, the main problem is the `a` array that is too big to fit in the L3. Indeed, when size is >128, `a` takes more than `128*64*64*8*2 = 8 MiB/process`. Actually, `a` is built from two array that must be read so the space needed in cache is 3 time bigger than that: ie. >24 MiB/process. The thing is all processes allocate the same amount of memory, so the **bigger the number of processes the bigger the cumulative space taken by `a`**. When the cumulative space is bigger than the cache, the processor needs to **write data to the RAM and read it back** which is slow.

In fact, this is even worse: processes are not fully synchronized so some process can flush data needed by others due to the filling of `a`.

Furthermore, `b.conj()` creates a new array that may not be allocated at the same memory allocation every time so the processor also needs to write data back. This effect is dependent of the low-level allocator being used. One can use the `out` parameter so to fix this problem. That being said, the problem was not significant on my machine (using `out` was 2% faster with 6 processes and equally fast with 1 process).

Put it shortly, more processes access more data and the global amount of data do not fit in CPU caches decreasing performance since arrays need to be reloaded over and over.

---

### Frequency scaling

Modern-processors use frequency scaling (like turbo-boost) so to make (quite) sequential applications faster, but they cannot use the same frequency for all cores when they are doing computation because processors have a **limited power budget**. This results of a **lower theoretical scalability**. The thing is all processes are doing the same work so N processes running on N cores are not N times takes more time than 1 process running on 1 core.

When 1 process is created, two cores are operating at 4550-4600 MHz (and others are at 3700 MHz) while when 6 processes are running, all cores operate at 4300 MHz. This is enough to explain a difference up to 7% on my machine.

You can hardly control the turbo frequency but you can either disable it completely or control the frequency so the minimum-maximum frequency are both set to the base frequency. Note that the processor is free to use a much lower frequency in pathological cases (ie. throttling, when a critical temperature reached). I do see an improved behavior by tweaking frequencies (7~10% better in practice).

---

### Other effects

When the number of process is equal to the number of core, the OS do more context-switches of the process than if one core is left free for other tasks. Context-switches decrease a bit the performance of the process. THis is especially true when all cores are allocated because it is harder for the OS scheduler to avoid unnecessary migrations. This usually happens on PC with many running processes but not much on computing machines. This overhead is about 5-10% on my machine.

Note that the number of processes should not exceed the number of cores (and not hyper-threads). Beyond this limit, the performance are hardly predictable and many complex overheads appears (mainly scheduling issues).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation. As for frequency scaling and the things mentioned in other effects, I would expect their contribution to be independent on the size of the matrix 'a'  so they should not be the cause of the change in the plot at around (125,64,64) does this make sense?  (I was only using physical cores no HT). As for Cache trashing, since I am only calling 'b.conj' in each process I was expecting that only 'b' and not 'a' is loaded into CPU cache which would mean a total cache usage in case of 20 processes: 16(complex numbers 128 bit) * 1 * 64 * 64*20 = 1.25MB

Comment: If the effect was due to loading of the complete matrices 'a' into ram I would have expected to see the change already much earlier, since each process has its own 'a' they already don't fit into my L3 cache starting from (20,64,64). Sorry this might be a noob question but how to monitor RAM throughput ?.

Comment: I expect that too for frequency scaling (though I did not check that was true on my machine). For the cache, no, `a` needs to be loaded in the cache because it is read in the code.In fact, Numpy loads `b` but `b` is a moving part of `a` so in the end, `a` is fully loaded. Processors use set-associative caches and are not aware the previous part of `a` loaded can be replaced. Since the virtual address of loaded values are increasing, the processor load new data contiguously in the L1 cache and it can overwrite important data during this process.

Comment: The caching algorithm of processor is not great when all input/out are read/written once. Cache misses can becomes problematic in this case but the thing is the processor do not have enough information to know what to evict properly. There are instruction to avoid this but they are not used by Numpy because it is not easy to know when to use them and this is not supported by all architecture. The best person to be able to use that is the end-user which is generally not aware of this problem when using Python (and generally do not care much).

Comment: I think what you miss in your analysis is that `a` need to be *fully* reloaded 20 times in each process. With 1 process, data can certainly fit entirely in cache so it does not need to be releaded and the next iterations can be significantly faster. In fact, data could theoretically be reused from multiple runs (and this is the case on my machine when the number of processes is the same and the size do not change).

Comment: Measuring the memory bandwidth is not so simple and poorly documented so it is not a noob question ;) . This is done using hardware counters that are architecture dependent (basically the name change from SandyBridge processors to Skylake or even to Skylake-SP ones, not to mention AMD Zen). Not all processors have such counters. Additionally, you need full root access to the machine to get this (for sake of security due to side-channel attack and code analysis). Technically, you can access to counters while being non-root but with special accesses/privileges (but it is complicated).

Comment: So basically, you need to use the Linux `perf` tool for that: list hardware counters first and search for memory-related ones like uncore IMC counters. If there is no such a thing, you can analyze the counters of the L3 cache misses (but this not as precise as analyzing IMC counters). Once found, you can use `perf stat -e THE_COUNTER_1,THE_COUNTER_2,...,THE_COUNTER_N YOUR_APPLICATION`. Note that you cannot read too many counters precisely: there is a limit (eg. 4 counters) where the OS will need to do some kind of (imprecise) multiplexing. Then you can divide the size by the time.

Comment: The analyzed part needs to be long enough (stable for >100 ms if possible) so results to be useful. Thus, you likely need to tweak the benchmark (which I did so to do the analysis on my machine). Note that you can also analyze data periodically when a program is run and many advanced things like this. For more information, consider reading [this](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

I'll accept Jérômes answer.
For the interested reader which could ask:
Why are you subdividing your big numpy array and only working on sub matrices?
The answer is, that it's faster!

Lets consider a complex Matrix 'a' which is 128MB big (to big to fit in cache).

For a single proccess one can quickly check that in

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
a=np.random.rand(8192,32,32)+1.j*np.random.rand(8192,32,32)
print(timeit.timeit('a.conj()',number=100,globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit('for i in range(0,8192,8): a[i:i+8].conj()',number = 100 ,globals = globals()))
```

the second timeit which iterates over 128kB sub-matrices finishes faster than the first (if 128kB is somewhere between your L1 and L2 cache sizes).

In the following plots I'll show computation time vs sub-matrix size computed on two test machines . There are two plots for each test case which cover the sub-matrix size ranges 16kB - 1024kB (using 16kB steps) and 0.5MB - 64MB (using 0.5MB steps) respectively.

**Machine I:  2 * Xenon  E5-2640 v3(L1i=L1d=32KB, L2=256KB, L3=20MB, 10 cores)**
[image]
[image]
**Machine II: 2 * Xenon  E5-2640 v4(L1i=L1d=32KB, L2=256KB, L3=50MB, 20 cores)**
[image]
[image]

The sub-matrix size for which the calculation is completed the quickest (64KB) is suspiciously exactly the size of the combined L1 cache of the two CPUs on each of the test Machines.
At the value of the combined L2 cache (512KB) nothing special is happening.
As soon as the combined sub-matrix size of all paralell running processes exceeds the L3 cache of one of the available CPUs the computation time starts to increase rapidly.(Eg. Machine 1, 19 processes, at ~ 1MB, Machine 2, 37 processes, at ~1.3MB)

Here is the script for the plots:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import numpy as np
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
m_shape =(8192,32,32)
def f(q,size):
    a = np.random.rand(*m_shape) + 1.j*np.random.rand(*m_shape)
    start = time.time()
    n=a.shape[0]    
    for i in range(0,n,size):
        a[i:i+size].conj()
    duration = time.time()-start
    q.put(duration)

def speed_test(number_of_processes=1,size=1):
    number_of_processes = number_of_processes
    process_list=[]
    queue = Queue()
    #Start processes
    for p_id in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=f,args=(queue,size))
        process_list.append(p)
        p.start()
    #Wait until all processes are finished
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()

    output = []
    while queue.qsize() != 0:
        output.append(queue.get())
    return np.mean(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes=np.arange(1,20,3)
    data=[[] for i in processes]

    ## L1 L2 cache data range
    sub_matrix_sizes = list(range(1,64,1))

    ## L3 cache data range
    #sub_matrix_sizes = list(range(32,4098,32))
    #sub_matrix_sizes.append(8192)
    
    for p_id,p in enumerate(processes):
        for size_0 in sub_matrix_sizes:
            data[p_id].append(speed_test(number_of_processes=p,size=size_0))
        print('{} of {} finished.'.format(p_id+1,len(processes)))

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from xframe.presenters.matplolibPresenter import plot1D
    data = np.array(data)
    sub_size_in_kb = np.array(sub_matrix_sizes)*np.dtype(complex).itemsize*np.prod(m_shape[1:])/1024
    sub_size_in_mb = sub_size_in_kb/1024

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    for d in data:
        ax.plot(sub_size_in_kb,d)
    
    ax.set_xlabel('Matrix Size in KB')
    #ax.set_xlabel('Matrix Size in MB')
    ax.set_ylabel('Runtime in seconds')
    fig.savefig('result.png')
    print('done.')
```

Comment: This is interesting but I find the discussion a bit confusing since you start saying "that it's faster" and the graphs show the opposite . It make sense when one know that more processes compute more data (kind of weak scaling). Still, I think strong scaling is a bit more intuitive for such graphs.

Comment: But even if we consider the case of a single process (dark blue lines) the graphs show that in case of Machine 1 conjugating matrix 'a' by iterating over 64 KB sub-matrices takes ~0.016 seconds where as splitting the matrix in only two halves (right most datapoint in the second plot with x-axis in MB) takes about 0.042 seconds. So iterating over many small 64 KB matrices seems to be about 2.6 times faster. Maybe the graphs are a bit confusing ...

Comment: The two graphs per test case should be viewed side-by-side, since the second continues the first with different sampling on the x axis.